# Show me how `String n = null;` works?

Tags: java

This is my code, and it works exactly how I want it to, but I picked up using

`String n = null;`

when dealing with switch statements, can someone explain to me why it works the way it does in this code so that I can better understand this concept?

```java
//Tells a user what number corresponds with what numbers on a telephone

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KeyPad 
{
   public static void main (String [] args) 
   {
   //Initialize Scanner
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Variables
   String x;
   char c;

   //Input
   System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
   x = input.next();

   //Convert to lowercase
   x = x.toLowerCase();
   c = x.charAt(0);

   //Assign reference variable 
   String n = null;

   //Switch conditions
   switch (c)
      {   
      case 'a':
      case 'b':
      case 'c': n = "2";
         break;
      case 'd':
      case 'e':
      case 'f': n = "3";
         break;
      case 'g':
      case 'h':
      case 'i': n = "4";
         break;
      case 'j':
      case 'k':
      case 'l': n = "5";
         break;
      case 'm':
      case 'n':
      case 'o': n = "6";
         break;
      case 'p':
      case 'q':
      case 'r':
      case 's': n = "7";
         break;
      case 't':
      case 'u':
      case 'v': n = "8";
         break;
      case 'w':
      case 'x':
      case 'y':
      case 'z': n = "9";
         break;                                 
      }       
   //Output
   System.out.println("The corresponding number is " + n);    
   }
}
```

Comment: What part about the above code is causing you trouble?

Comment: Nothing is causing me trouble, it works, and I just recently added a default statement to it, that I forgot earlier. I want to understand why the 'null' statement works the way it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are either asking "Why do I set the string n equal to null?" or "Why does my switch statement work correctly?" So I will answer both.

First, You are setting the string to null first to ensure that it is blank, and contains no data( or to a memory location of "0" ).  Basically, you are telling the compiler that n is actually nothing at all, it doesn't even exist, except for in its name.

Now, on to the switch statement. You have your standard fall through switch statement.  So if the variable c in your snippet is one of the letters "a" "b" or "c" it will then set the string n ( which until this point is still nothing, if you attempt to use it it will throw an error ) and sets it to the string "2"(I assume you know the difference between strings and integers ).

You may be thinking, why does n still exist after the switch statement( or why is it still not null )?  This is because of the scope of the variable.  Since it was declared inside of main, anything inside of main will be able to see, and change the value of n. now if you did the following

```
.
.
.
string n = null;
switch(c)
{
    case "a":
    case "b":
    case "c":
        string n="2";
        break
    .
    .
    .
}
System.out.println("The corresponding number is " + n);
```

You would get an error, since you re-declared n, in the scope of the switch statement.  In this example the n in the switch statement DOES NOT have the same scope as the n being printed.  Where as in your example the "case "c": n=2;" n DOES have the same scope( and in fact the same variable ) as the n being printed to the screen.

Also, just a quick fyi, You could also use this method as a check to see that n was in fact set to something before printing it ( and prevent troublesome ArgumentNull exceptions ).

```
if(n!=null)
    System.out.println("The corresponding number is " + n);
else
    System.out.println("The character you entered does not have a corresponding number");
```

I hope this helps clear things up a bit!

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of scope. The Java language considers the entire body of a switch statement as a single scope--it does not try to do in-depth analysis of code paths. For example, the following could spell trouble:

```
switch(foo){
    case 1:
        int i = 1;
        // note no break
    case 2:
        int i = 4;
}
```

This would effectively be a double-declaration. Or, the following could be problematic, and the compiler doesn't analyze it, thus assuming that it *would* be problematic:

```
switch(foo){
    case 1:
        int i = 1;
        // note no break
    case 2:
        i = 4;
}
```

To handle this, the entire switch block is treated as a single scope. You must declare the variable once in this scope, *and* you must ensure that all code paths will actually give the variable a value, by immediately initializing it to `null`. The null value simply indicates the *lack* of an object, as opposed to `String s;` which might never get initialized by some otherwise-valid code path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to understand that you have to look after the bytecode of such a class.
In order to clarify I've created a test class as follow:

```
switch(c){

    case 1:
        String temp = "first";
        System.out.println(temp);
        break;
    case 2:
        temp = "second";
        System.out.println(temp);
        break;
    case 3:
        String temp2 = "third";
        System.out.println(temp2);

}
```

Using the javap to generate the bytecode, we get the following LocalVariableTable:

> ```
> LocalVariableTable:
>   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
>          0      65     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
>          2      63     1     c   I
>         31      10     2  temp   Ljava/lang/String;
>         44      10     2  temp   Ljava/lang/String;
>         57       7     3 temp2   Ljava/lang/String;
> ```

What that table of local variables tell us is:

1. There is a variable of type String named temp which has a valid context from instruction 31 to 41 (31 + 10)
2. There is a another variable of type String named temp which has a valid context from instruction 44 to 54 (44 + 10)
3. There is another variable of type String named temp2 which has a valid context from 57 to 64 (57 + 7)

So, the compiler does not treated the whole switch block as one scope, it did created two distinct scopes for the "String temp" variable.

If you try another example, as the source code bellow:

```
//first scope
{
    String myLocal = "first";
    System.out.println(myLocal);
}
//second scope
{
    String myLocal = "second";
    System.out.println(myLocal);
}
```

The respective bytecode points to the following LocalVariableTable:

> LocalVariableTable:
>         Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
>               67       7     2 myLocal   Ljava/lang/String;
>               77       7     2 myLocal   Ljava/lang/String;

What shows that two scopes was created for variable myLocal of type String. Exactly the same way it created for the switch statement.

In your case the switch statement just use a LocalVariableTable which has a scope that covers the whole switch statement, that is the main reason you can set a String declared outside the switch. The code bellow illustrate that:

```
int c = 5;
String temp = null;

switch(c){

case 1:
    temp = "first";
    System.out.println(temp);
    break;
case 2:
    temp = "second";
    System.out.println(temp);
    break;
}
```

Now, notice the bytecode generate:

> ```
> LocalVariableTable:
>   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
>          0      89     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
>          2      87     1     c   I
>          4      85     2  temp   Ljava/lang/String;
> ```

Here you can see the "String temp" variable has a scope of length 85, what covers the whole switch statement, what allows you to reference the variable inside it.

Sorry for the long answer, but such a question is like ask a mathematician to explain what a function means. In order to answer you question is necessary to understand deep concept of how source code works behind the scenes.

Hope this can help, regards.